# Hooking up a function to window resize operation in R

Tags: r, window-resize

I have a function that shows a plot consisting mainly a lot of text (a modified version of the wordcloud function from the wordcloud package). Resizing the window without resizing the text looks bad. I would like to create a custom hook for a function called whenever the plot window is resized.

How can I do this, programatically, in R, if it can be done at all?

Comment: Why do you need to resize? Why not create the window with the size desired?  `windows(3,5)` , or a similar `quartz.new` call if you're using OS X.  If you then copy or save the window as an emf or other advanced format,  the graph and the text will scale properly in whatever app you paste it into.

Comment: Because I check visually whether the tag cloud looks as I think it should. Also, because the wordcloud algorithm is not perfect, and sometimes changing the shape of the window can improve the output. And, finally, because I am curious.

Comment: Might be worth looking at Rggobi, iplots, and playwith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This document](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/grid/doc/displaylist.pdf) talks about the display list and what happens when graphics are resized.  I don't see a way to redo the calculations with base graphics, though there may be a hook that can be set.  If you use grid graphics instead of base graphics then the linked document has some suggestions that may trigger the recalculations you want.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That is grid specific, but then, I just use the grid.